# Python parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have created the root like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

And here's a sample of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed gd:etag="&quot;Rn84fzVSLyt7I2A9XRVbFkwOQAE.&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <id>moha****ee@gmail.com</id>
 <updated>2015-08-03T15:12:37.137Z</updated>
 <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
 <title>Mohammad Amin's Contacts</title>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mohamma***ee%40gmail.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mohamm***aee%40gmail.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moha****ee%40gmail.com/full/batch"/>
 <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moham***ee%40gmail.com/full?max-results=25"/>
 <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moha****aee%40gmail.com/full?max-results=25&amp;start-index=26"/>
 <author>
  <name>Mohammad Amin</name>
  <email>moha****ee@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
 <generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>131</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
 <entry gd:etag="&quot;SXc5cTNQJit7I2A9XRRbGEsPQQY.&quot;">
  <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moh***ee%40gmail.com/base/15281000e768a31</id>
  <updated>2015-04-12T19:07:08.929Z</updated>
  <app:edited xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">2015-04-12T19:07:08.929Z</app:edited>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <title>Sina Ghazi</title>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/moh***aee%40gmail.com/15****a31" gd:etag="&quot;WR1-e34pSit7I2BlWW4TbChNHHg6LF88WhE.&quot;"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/moham****aee%40gmail.com/full/1528****8a31"/>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mohamm***ee%40gmail.com/full/15***a31"/>
  <gd:name>
   <gd:fullName>Si***i</gd:fullName>
   <gd:givenName>Si***a</gd:givenName>
   <gd:familyName>G***zi</gd:familyName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="si***i@gmail.com" primary="true"/>
  <gContact:website href="http://www.google.com/profiles/1167****31" rel="profile"/>
 </entry>
.....
```

I'm using XPath and I can extract the *address* attribute quite easily.

```
for item in root.findall('.//{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005}email'):
        email = item.get('address')
```

But when I want to get the *title* attribute it returns None. Any ideas?

Comment: show the code you used to extract the *address* tag. Btw, I can't find any address *tag*, did you mean *attribute*?

Comment: Yes. You're right. It was address attribute.

Comment: There is no "title" attribute in the XML. But there is a `{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title` element in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
for item in root.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title'):
    title = item.text
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a section in the python documentation about [parsing xml with namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces).

You could either use har07s way, which works perfectly well, or you could do it like this if you don't want to type the whole namespace multiple times:

```
ns = {'ns': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}

for element in root.findall('.//ns:title', ns):
    title = element.text
```

Comment: Is there a way I can loop through the file and extract each item with it's order? I don't want to extract emails and then titles. Can I do it at the same time?

Comment: @AminA You can iterate over `<entry>` nodes and then extract email address and title from each.